# How can we manage the IP change on local Bugzilla. My System IP address is changing automatically and i have hosted my bugziila on local machine

Tags: manual-testing, defect-tracking, qa-process, testing-team, bugzilla

How can we manage the IP change on local Bugzilla. My System IP address is changing automatically and i have hosted my bugziila on local machine.
Due to changing the System ip address my teammates not able to access the bugilla properly, Please suggest me the setup process for IP change, where i have to make change when my ip got change.

Answer (score 1):

Use hostname instead with one of many dynamic DNS service providers. You'll have the same domain name to access the Bugzilla application even when your IP changes.